# clang error when adding typecast in method of a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang++

I have a template struct that takes as parameters the type of a method and the pointer to a method and wraps it in a C-like function:

```
template <typename T, T> struct proxy;

template <typename T, typename R, typename ...Args, R (T::* mf)(Args...)>
struct proxy<R (T::*)(Args...), mf>
{
    static R call(T& obj, Args&&... args)
    {
        return (obj.*mf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

The *proxy* struct works in simple scenarios as expected, eg:

```
struct Foo
{
    int foo(int x)
    {
        return x + 1;
    }
};

...
Foo f;
proxy<int(Foo::*)(int), &Foo::foo>::call(f, 10);
```

The problem is when I use *proxy* inside macros that may unroll into:

```
proxy<decltype((int(Foo::*)(int))(&Foo::foo)), (int(Foo::*)(int))(&Foo::foo)>::call(f, 10);
```

in *clang* and the error is:

```
error: non-type template argument is not a pointer to member constant
proxy<decltype((int(Foo::*)(int))(&Foo::foo)), (int(Foo::*)(int))(&Foo::foo)>::call(f, 10);
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

On the other hand GCC 4.8 is not reporting any error and everything works as expected.

My questions are:

1. is there a way to workaround clang's error and
2. is this a bug in clang that I should probably report?

Comment: Can we see the macro by chance?  It probably doesn't matter, but just curious.

Comment: This cast shouldn't be required. The overload selection should work since you've already specified the type via the previous template arguments. The problem probably is that a pointer non-type template argument must be written as `&` *id-expression* or just *id-expression* for ordinary (non-member) functions.

Comment: `decltype((int(Foo::*)(int))(&Foo::foo))` That's one weird expression. If you have a type to convert to, why do you use `decltype` and a cast? Or is this from the macro argument?

Comment: Erratum: a pointer-to-member as a non-type template argument must be expressed "as described in 5.3.1" which talks about forming such a pointer via `&class_name::member_name`. This probably leads to the same restriction: casts aren't allowed.

Comment: The macro is:

    #define ANKI_LUA_METHOD_FLAGS(name_, methodPtr_, flags_) \
        ANKI_LUA_FUNCTION_AS_METHOD_FLAGS(name_, \
            (&proxy<decltype(methodPtr_), methodPtr_>::func), flags_)

Comment: Can you change the macro?

Comment: Or remove the cast? (Or were you trying to use it to select a particular overload of `foo`?)

Answer (score 1):

Your macro generates standards non-compliant code.  In particular, a cast is **not allowed** in a in a non-type method pointer template argument.  It is also redundant in this case.

So the easiest way to fix this is to change the macro:

```
#define WORKING_LUA_METHOD_FLAGS(name_, methodType_, methodPtr_, flags_) \
  ANKI_LUA_FUNCTION_AS_METHOD_FLAGS(name_, \
  (&proxy<methodType_, methodPtr_>::func), flags_)
```

And at point of use:

```
ANKI_LUA_METHOD_FLAGS( "bob", (int(Foo::*)(int))(&Foo::foo), empty_flags )
```

becomes:

```
WORKING_LUA_METHOD_FLAGS( "bob", int(Foo:::*)(int), &Foo::foo, empty_flags )
```

and now it is correct according to the standard.  Note `"bob"` and `empty_flags` are just placeholders for whatever really goes there.  The name replacement may or may not be required.

Comment: @dyp would you believe copy paste coding on phone?

Comment: Maybe you need one with a larger display? ;)