# Converting member function pointers in templates

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, pointer-to-member

Suppose I have the following two classes:

```
template<typename T>
struct Base
{
    void foo();
};

struct Derived : Base<Derived> {};
```

I can do this:

```
void (Derived::*thing)() = &Derived::foo;
```

And the compiler is happy (as I would expect).

When I put this in two levels of templates suddenly it explodes:

```
template<typename T, T thing>
struct bar {};

template<typename T>
void foo()
{
    bar<void (T::*)(),&T::foo>{};
}

int main()
{
    foo<Derived>();  // ERROR
    foo<Base<Derived>>(); // Works fine
}
```

This fails with:

```
non-type template argument of type 'void (Base<Derived>::*)()' cannot be converted to a value of type 'void (Derived::*)()'
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/NnN0Rx)

Why does the simple case work and the more complicated one fail?  I believe this is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022373/clang-error-when-adding-typecast-in-method-of-a-template-parameter) question but am not entirely sure....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[@YSC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52315296/817643) nailed the type of `&Derived::foo;`. Since you are wondering why this implicit conversion...

```
void (Derived::*thing)() = &Derived::foo;
```

... flies normally but not in the template, the reason is as follows:

> [temp.arg.nontype]
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.nontype#2) A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a
>   converted constant expression of the type of the template-parameter.
>
> [expr.const]
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#4) A converted constant expression of type T is an expression,
>   implicitly converted to type T, where the converted expression is a
>   constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only
>
> - [...]

The list I omitted does not contain [pointer to member conversions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.mem). Thus making that template argument invalid for the parameter you specify.

---

A trivial fix would be to use `decltype(&T::foo)` instead of `void (T::*)()` as the type argument. This is a well-formed replacement:

```
bar<decltype(&T::foo), &T::foo>{};
```

Whether or not is acceptable, is of course dependent on your use case, beyond the scope of the MCVE.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `&Derived::foo` is in fact of type `void (Base<Derived>::*)()`:

> #### [`[expr.unary]/3`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.unary#op-3)
>
> The result of the unary & operator is a pointer to its operand. The operand shall be an lvalue or a qualified-id. If the operand is a qualified-id naming a non-static or variant member m of some class C with type T, the result has type “pointer to member of class C of type T” and is a prvalue designating C​::​m.

Note the *"member m of some class C with type T"*... Terrible wording.

Comment: How would you word it better?

Comment: @Barry I hoped no one would question it, dammit! This was a non-constructive critic; you should not make such critics, I should not make such critics, no one should. Yet everybody does sometimes ^^

Comment: I mean, the wording isn't like... chiseled in granite. If you can think of a way to word it better, it can be changed.

Comment: @Barry What disturbs me is that all situations where `[axpr.unary]/3` mattered to me were when forming a pointer to a member of a class through its (direct) child class. But this wording "of some class" doesn't strike. With OP's example, when I write `&Derived::foo`, I'd interpret "some class" as being `Derived`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is going to be an error even without templates, for example if your classes were not templates:

```
struct Base {
    void foo();
};

struct Derived : Base {};
```

You still can't do `foo<Base>()`: https://ideone.com/MQE0ff

---

A possible alternative solution would involve, first for simplification, rather than taking 2 template parameters I'm going to have `bar` use the `auto` template parameter type:

```
template<auto thing>
struct bar{};
```

Next we'd need to implement `is_specialization_of`:

```
template<template<typename...> class T, typename U>
struct is_specialization_of : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename...> class T, typename... Ts> 
struct is_specialization_of<T, T<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};
```

Now we can rewrite `foo` to use `is_specialization_of` we can determine if we're passed a `Base` specialization or another class (which we presume derives from a `Base` specialization.)

```
template<typename T>
void foo()
{
    conditional_t<is_specialization_of<Base, T>::value, bar<&T::foo>, bar<&Base<T>::foo>>{};
}
```

I've expanded your example slightly to actually call `thing` in `bar` and just otherwise incorporated my suggestions. You can check that out here: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a33b8bd38896ff5

Comment: This looks like a comment ;)

Comment: @YSC Yeah :( I accidentally committed while I was typing up the example in the other window... And then it turned out it took me way longer to finish. (I'm still learning a lot on template stuff so I'm kinda slow.)